# OpenLayers/GeoServer Image mosaic

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, geotiff-tiff, mosaic

I would like to understand why I can't change the files of my mosaic directory in GeoServer. When I create my layers, I specify the URL of my directory with GeoTIFF files and shapefiles. If you change GeoTIFF files and shapes files with new GeoTIFF files (and shape), I see nothing in preview image (OpenLayers).

EDIT : ERROR in GEOSERVER

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The specified coverageName is unavailable
    at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.ImageMosaicReader.checkUnspecifiedCoverage(ImageMosaicReader.java:1092)
    at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.ImageMosaicReader.getMetadataValue(ImageMosaicReader.java:1005)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.SingleGridCoverage2DReader.getMetadataValue(SingleGridCoverage2DReader.java:86)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.CoverageDimensionCustomizerReader.getMetadataValue(CoverageDimensionCustomizerReader.java:292)
    at org.geoserver.web.data.resource.DimensionEditor.<init>(DimensionEditor.java:149)
    at org.geoserver.web.data.resource.ResourceDimensionsTabPanelInfo.<init>(ResourceDimensionsTabPanelInfo.java:58)
    ... 108 more
```

Comment: OpenLayers doesn't support geotiff directly.  What other software are you using?

Comment: @Mike I forget to mention GeoServer my bad...

Comment: did you change the names of the files? did you reload the config? what did the log file say?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: @IanTurton ok I just edited my post